# Slow and incomplete boot to command line

Tags: boot, 16.04

I've been trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 on a Dell OptiPlex 9020, and I consistently get the following error message thrown during boot:

`INFO: task systemd-udevd:186 blocked for more than 120 seconds.`

`Not tainted 4.8.0-46-generic #49~16.04.1-Ubuntu`

Eventually the system boots to the command line, though this error message still pops up then as well.

Install Ubuntu 14.xx on the system doesn't produce this problem.

Is this a problem with the new GRUB boot system, on this particular machine? A kernel bug? Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: Impossible to tell from what little you posted. I suggest you file a bug report on launchpad against systemd.

Comment: I can do that. Is there anything else to post here that could help troubleshoot?

Comment: No but if you search launchpad there are similar bug reports.